# Synchronizing between a framework listener and events during startup

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

OSGi version 5, via Felix version 4.4.1.

I'm embedding the framework, purely via the OSGi API, nothing Felix-specific. So, I use the SPI to obtain the framework class name, create an instance, and init it.

Then I install bundles, start all the bundles, and `start()` the framework.

Now, if something goes wrong, a framework event will be delivered. Felix delivers these on a separate thread. How can I synchronize event delivery with `start()` returning? `FrameworkStartLevel.setStartLevel` has an option to accept listeners and guarantee that they will be called before it returns, but that only helps if I'm going to bump the start level above 1. I guess I could set all the bundles to start level 2, and thus defer their startup until I made a call to bump the level to 2, and thus get the desired sync. Is there any simpler way to just leave everything at level 1?

Comment: Can't you call install your bundles after you started the framework?

Comment: I see that installBundle throws; are exceptions thrown by activators delivered there, or off to the side as framework events.

Comment: if you call installBundle, that does not necessarily start the bundle, so the exceptions cannot come fromthe activator of the bundle.